# What text should be used - 'Save for Later' or 'Add to Wishlist' or 'Bookmark it' or 'Shortlist it'?

Tags: website-design, web-app, user-expectation, e-commerce, mobile-web

I'm creating eCommerce web products (website, mobile-site, mobile-app) and on the products' listing page, I want to give users a choice to save any product, that they don't want to buy right now, but might/would buy later.

Many websites have been calling this feature by multiple names:

- Save for Later
- Add to Wishlist
- Bookmark it
- Shortlist it

Which one these name (text) communicates the purpose instantly to the users?

Comment: Surprisingly Amazon.com has three things... Add to Wishlist, Add to Shopping List and also Save for Later. Would never recommend such things that are actually doing almost the same thing. But if Amazon is doing it then surely they might have had researched thoroughly. But it would be very interesting to know more about this from them :)

Answer (score 3):

Probably **"Save for later"** is the most business-driving option from the choices you put above I think. It's a direct message that he or she would buy it next time.

**"Add to wishlist"** is also ok, but wishlist might be something people aren't viewing very often.

I wouldn't choose the other two.

Comment: I agree with this - a wish list is something that the user wants but won't/can/t get for themselves at this moment and could be a collection of items.  Save for later is similar to saying 'I am going to come back to this and buy it', almost like a provisional basket.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about research. Maybe someone else has more experience on this and can share their knowledge. But I can give some thoughts on your options:

- Save for Later: Read the product later (whether it is an article or product description, specifications...)
- Add to Wishlist: User **wishes to have** the item but it is not possible for him right now
- Bookmark it: Similar to the Save for later but might not imply the user didn't have time to check it properly the first time
- Shortlist it: I'm not sure about this one.

In my opinion the **Wishlist suggests the user that he wants the item**. Also when visiting the site, accessing the wishlist might make the user feel as he needs the item again, as he wanted it before but couldn't obtain it.

Comment: Wishlist actually reminds me of a kid christmas letter :)